# SQL Server formatting keys without quotes and forcing single quotes on string values

Tags: sql, json, prisma

I am trying to output data from multiple SQL tables into formatted JSON.

For Instance:

```
SELECT [msdb_version].[id],
       [msdb_version].[version_string],
       [msdb_version].[version_major],
       [msdb_version].[version_minor],
       [msdb_version].[version_build],
       [msdb_version].[version_revision] FROM [msdb].[dbo].[msdb_version] FOR JSON AUTO,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES;
```

Results:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "version_string": "13.0.5103.6",
    "version_major": 13,
    "version_minor": 0,
    "version_build": 5103,
    "version_revision": 6
}]
```

I want the result formatted this way so I can use it in a typescript file for Prisma client.

```
[{
    id: 1,
    version_string: '13.0.5103.6',
    version_major: 13,
    version_minor: 0,
    version_build: 5103,
    version_revision: 6
}]
```

I have tried using replace function on string, but that is replace removing all quotes.

Sample seed.ts

```
import { PrismaClient, reftimezone } from '@prisma/client';

const refTimeZoneSeeds: reftimezone[] = [
  {
    RefTimeZoneId: 1,
    CountryCode: 'US',
    Name: 'Alaskan',
    Timezone: 'US/Alaska',
  },
  {
    RefTimeZoneId: 2,
    CountryCode: 'US',
    Name: 'Aleutian Islands',
    Timezone: 'US/Aleutian',
  },
  {
    RefTimeZoneId: 3,
    CountryCode: 'US',
    Name: 'Mountain Standard Time (Arizona)',
    Timezone: 'US/Arizona',
  },
  {
    RefTimeZoneId: 4,
    CountryCode: 'US',
    Name: 'Central Time',
    Timezone: 'US/Central',
  },
 
];

export async function seedRefTimeZone(prisma: PrismaClient): Promise<void> {
  await prisma.$transaction(async (prisma) => {
    for (const data of refTimeZoneSeeds) {
      await prisma.reftimezone.upsert({
        where: { RefTimeZoneId: data.RefTimeZoneId },
        update: {
          CountryCode: data.CountryCode,
          Name: data.Name,
          Timezone: data.Timezone,
        },
        create: data,
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Sql script to generate code

Comment: …why are you doing this?

Comment: The JSON specification _requires_ quoted property names - and all JSON can be consumed directly by JS code/engines - I’m curious why you want to generate _invalid_ JSON or why you think Prisma needs it

Comment: this is part of "code generator"?

Comment: Added a sample of the seed.ts file. I am trying to get SQL Server to output the data array. I can create a function, pass in the table name and have it output the code needed for seed.ts file.

Comment: @DennisT You haven't responded to my remarks about how/why quoted property-names in JSON are illegal/invalid.

Comment: @Dai - It is an object used by the prisma client to seed the database: https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/latest/typescript/graphql/prisma/seed.ts

Comment: @DennisT Right, but I can't see anything that suggests you actually _need_ to trim double-quotes from JSON object property names. Where are you getting that idea from?

Comment: @dai - From the example listed on Prisma Git hub - here is the link again https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/latest/typescript/graphql/prisma/seed.ts

Comment: @DennisT Where in that example you linked to does it say you have to remove quotes around property names?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252815/discussion-between-dennist-and-dai).